# Schedule an Email Two Weeks After Signup with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a web application that has ActionMailer already successfully running, and it sends an email to the user when they complete the signup. At the same time this email gets sent, I would also like an email to be scheduled to send to them two weeks in the future. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at delayed jobs, something like [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html) or [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). Without more info on what you've tried and your code, it'll be hard to get a specific answer - have a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if you can tighten it up at all and I'm sure people'll help out :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look into it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To those interested in this, I ended up just making a Ruby function that checked which users had signed up more than two weeks ago every time I visited the Admin Panel on my site. If any user had been registered for 2 weeks or more, but had not yet received the 2-week email, a div would appear with a button to manually send the email to that user. This seemed easier to me than trying to create a scheduler simply because I would visit the Admin Panel every day.

Comment: At least I found a solution. Better than anyone else could do.

Answer (score -1):

Make a ruby method that get users where:

```
user.created_at.to_date == DateTime.now.to_date - 2.week
```

Then make a `crontab` calling that method every day.

profit.

Comment: This runs the very real risk of mailing people multiple times if you're not careful.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @tadman how is that even possible? only if you change the created_at field of a user... see that you are checking with == not >=.

Comment: @JuanManuelRodulfoSalcedo You should have some kind of other field like `last_mailed_at` which can be part of the clause, too, where you update that if you successfully send mail. This means if the cron job runs twice one day you're not going to send twice.